# How do I DM a person with Discord.py??? Why won't my code work?

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Running...')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    while True:
        user = client.get_user('user')
        await user.send('hi')
```

I have tried a million variations of this and it won't work.
Why won't send work????????

Answer (score -1):

I just tested this with the latest version of pycord and it works.

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio

TOKEN = "TOKEN_HERE"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents, members = True, messages = True, message_content = True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Running...")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    user_id = message.author.id
    user = await client.fetch_user(user_id)
    await user.send("HI")
        
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I don't know why you had a while loop in there, I don't think it was needed. I used client.fetch_user as the method for getting the member object and included the intents for messages and members otherwise the bot won't be able to read messages or access member objects. You will need to make sure you have the intents enabled in your developer account for this to work.

Comment: Please do not answer questions if you do not have enough details. If the question is missing details, you should flag it and leave a comment once you have the reputation. Please see [answer] :)